# How do I install a front page using html/css on my webdomain?

Tags: html, css, dns, file-structure

I intend to install a front page on 'darraghkenny.ie' -while I do some testing darraghkenny.ie/alpha/. 
I would like to do a simple one in html/css so I can have some practice editing a live site while I use the darraghkenny.ie/alpha/ to build a wordpress site.
Within File manager in Hostgator control panel, I can see the 'alpha' and 'cgi-bin' folders. Should I just create html and css files here to get started or is this a big mistake?

(I know the question is broad so if there is a some reading required I would also appreciate a link to a suitable tutorial).

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In HostGator  all your website content should go in `public_html`
2. I recomend organizing you website resources, something like:

--public_html 
----index.html 
----pages
--------page1.html
--------page2.html
----css
--------css1.css
--------css2.css
----js
--------js1.js
--------js2.js

3. [Start Reading](http://www.w3schools.com/)

There are millions of tutorials regarding `html,css,js` for you to get started, just **Google it!** you'll see that  **UPLOADING** webpages to your website is a piece of cake.

BTW: HostGator has a couple of tutorials for you to understand where you website resources should be placed (public_html).

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Esteban, I have been building locally for a while but was a bit paranoid to start on the big bad web. Got started now, thanks a mill.